# NGINX url rewrite to relative not working

Tags: php, magento, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to use url rewrite in NGINX, but it doesn't work. Currently am using IP address to access the site.

rewrite ^/mytest/(.*)?.html$ /mytest.html?$1 last;

However, when I add the absolute URL, then it does.

rewrite ^/mytest/(.*)?.html$ http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mytest.html?$1 last;

I would like to use relative url so that the url doesn't change and remain as it is.

The entire nginx config ...

http {

```
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

index   index.php index.html index.htm;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  xx.xxx.xxx.xxx;
    root         /export/www/mysite/htdocs;

    rewrite ^/mytest/(.*)?.html$ mytest.html?$1 last;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^(.+)$ /index.php last; }
            try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /40x.html {
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root    /export/www/mysite/htdocs;
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/spool/phpfpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }


    try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; 
    expires off;

    ## Static conetnt cache
    location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
       expires 30d;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }

location @handler {
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { 
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ .php$ { 
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content

        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/spool/phpfpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You forgot to prepend slash. It should be `/mytest.html?$1`

Comment: Thanks Alexey, that was typo. Just updated, it doesn't work with slash also.

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "not working"? You want it to change url in browser?

Comment: Hi Alexey... Actually when I do not use absolute url, rewrite does not happen at all. However, when I add absolute url, the redirection takes place. But I am looking for rewrite without absolute url, I do not want the url to change in browser.

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem, only the absolute redirect works. Would be great if someone could look at this more closely.